# Twitter Android integration

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter4j, socialauth

I am running into problems every time trying to authenticate twitter and post a tweet from my application. I have used Socialauth and Twitter4j before to no avail. Has anyone tried this tutorial and got it working ?
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

I have Facebook working perfectly. It seems like twitter is just so much more complicated for no reason. Can anybody recommended which library or jar is best to use when using twitter inside an android application.

All I want to do is post a tweet inside app.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: You say "to no avail" can you be more specific with regard to the issue you are encountering?

Comment: Well the first problem was the callback url but now its throwing back an authentication error. I have reset the keys and made a application several times.

Comment: hi please download the new jar : https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=45&can=1